# A property of inner products

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, vectors, inner-products

Let $H$ be an inner product space. Show that if $\sum_ku_k$ converges in $H$, then

$\langle\sum_ku_k,g\rangle=\sum_k\langle  u_k,g\rangle$, where $ u_k,g\in H$.

This propery seems to follow directly from the axioms of inner products, but i am not sure if i am missing something. How would you prove this result?

Comment: Why don't you show what you did?

Comment: I did. I said from the axioms of the inner product it should be justified to move the summation in and out of the innerproduct freely.

Comment: Yes, but you just restated the problem. Of course it follows from the axioms of the inner product, otherwise it wouldn't be true. The point is to show that it's true, and show that it does follow.

Comment: In that case i need help beginning

Answer (score 2):

Set $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} u_k = v$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Assume for convenience that $g \neq 0$, as otherwise the result is trivial.

By the convergence of the sequence $( \sum_{k = 1}^{N} u_k )_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \to v$, we know there exists $N_0$ such that $ \left\| v - \sum_{k = 1}^{N} u_k \right\| < ( \epsilon / \| g \| )^2$ for $N \geq N_0$. We know by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that if $N \geq N_0$, then
\begin{align*}
\left| \left< v - \sum_{k = 1}^{N} u_k , g \right> \right|^2 & \leq \left\| v - \sum_{k = 1}^{N} u_k \right\|^2 \cdot \| g \|^2 \\
& < (\epsilon / \| g \|)^2 \cdot \| g \|^2 \\
& = \epsilon^2 \\
\Rightarrow \left| \left< v - \sum_{k = 1}^{N} u_k , g \right> \right| & < \epsilon .
\end{align*}
This establishes the convergence we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\displaystyle\sum_{k}u_{k}$ and $s_{n}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}u_{k}$, then $s_{n}\rightarrow u$ in $H$ and the continuity of first coordinate shows that
\begin{align*}
\left<u,g\right>=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left<s_{n},g\right>=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left<u_{k},g\right>=\sum_{k}\left<u_{k},g\right>.
\end{align*}

For the convergence: $\left|\left<s_{n}-u,g\right>\right|\leq\|s_{n}-u\|\|g\|\rightarrow 0$ and we use Squeeze Theorem to conclude.

Comment: Why is $$\langle  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}s_n,g\rangle=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\langle s_n,g\rangle?$$

Comment: This is by the continuity of $\left<\cdot,g\right>$ for fixed $g$.

Comment: I think the point is to establish that continuity.

Comment: I have added some details, thanks for reminding.